# Is a datagrid/gridview possible in SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I'm not asking as to how go about doing this, but just curious if its possible to list items in a data grid/ grid view as you would in asp.net websites, but in SharePoint using say web parts? Then be able to select a item in the grid and press a button that would then carry on out some task? Just need to find out if its possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.  You can do it with the standard GridView, but I've also done it with DevExpress ASPxGridView.

Comment: There is also the SPGridView which adds the extra SharePoint functionality to the standard GridView :)

Comment: Thanks, is this using the new Client Object Model in SharePoint 2010 I assume? Or is there a way even in 2007?

Comment: @James my experience has been with SharePoint 2007 using the Object Model.

Comment: @James No, the Client Object Model in 2010 is something different. You can use an SPGridView in a WebPart in SharePoint 2007. See http://www.reversealchemy.net/2009/05/01/building-a-spgridview-control-part-1-introducing-the-spgridview/